# oracle select mulitple records to 1 on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Table : CODES_TABLE

```
Serial   - Code -  DateTime
A123        B2          01/01/17:14:00
A124        B2          01/01/17:14:00
A123        B3          01/01/17:14:05
A123        B4          01/01/17:14:08
A124        B3          01/01/17:14:00
A128        B2          03/01/17:14:00
A129        B2          03/01/17:14:00
A129        B4          02/01/17:14:00
```

What Im trying to get is a list of all Serials which have generated a code B2, B3 and B4 And have generated it in a given order – i.e B2 first, then B3 then B4 So In this example – only Serial A123

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response... Im expecting back Serial A123 in the above example...  So far ive tried :  Select * from Codes_Table where ((Code = 'B2') OR ('Code='B3') OR (Code='B4'))    but cant really get my head around how then to check if they results occur in a date order...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, from your input data, that every `code` may only occure once for a `serial`, this could be a way:

```
/* test case */
with testTable(Serial,Code, DateTime) as (
    select 'A123',   'B2', to_date('01/01/17:14:00', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 'A124',   'B2', to_date('01/01/17:14:00', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 'A123',   'B3', to_date('01/01/17:14:05', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 'A123',   'B4', to_date('01/01/17:14:08', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 'A124',   'B3', to_date('01/01/17:14:00', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 'A128',   'B2', to_date('03/01/17:14:00', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 'A129',   'B2', to_date('03/01/17:14:00', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 'A129',   'B4', to_date('02/01/17:14:00', 'dd/mm/yy:hh24:mi') from dual
)
/* the query */
select serial
from testTable
group by serial
having listagg( case when code in ('B2', 'B3', 'B4') then code end) within group ( order by dateTime) like '%B2B3B4%'
```

The idea here is to aggregate by `serial`, building for each `serial` a string that contains the `codes`, ordered by `dateTime`.

Assuming that every `code` can only appear once for a `serial` the only `serials` that match your condition will have strings containing `'B2B3B4'`.

The `CASE` is used to handle the case you need to check if a serial has `B2, B3, B5` where even `B4` may occur.

This should better explain how this should work:

```
select serial, listagg( case when code in ('B2', 'B3', 'B4') then code end) within group ( order by dateTime) as string
from testTable
group by serial;

SERI STRING
---- ---------------
A123 B2B3B4
A124 B2B3
A128 B2
A129 B4B2
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksej,  So the codes (B2 and B3) can occur multiple times - but code B4 will only ever occur once - as long as a B2 and a B3 has occurred before it - then that's a result I want to see...

Comment: The important here is that for a single serial you don't have more than one 'B2', 'B3' or 'B4'; if they occur on different serials, no problem

Comment: You are a star!